# Bootstrapping an Swing application

Tags: java, spring, swing

I know to some of you it might sound ancient but I am currently developing an fat client using Swing for the user interface and Spring as a framework behind the scenes.

Is there any good tutorial explaining how to launch, initialize and shot-down a Swing application?

I saw there is a JSR 296 but it seems to be very old and not maintained any more.

Is there someone who could help me?

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly guessed JSR 296 has failed its purposes and since 2009, when it was announced that it wouldn't have been included in JDK 7, its development has been put on hold. Several forks emerged, and I've worked with most of them, including projects based on a Swing/RESTful architecture.

The best option IMHO is currently represented by [Netbeans Platform](https://netbeans.org/features/platform/), a generic framework for Swing applications that can leverage most of the components written to build the Netbeans IDE itself. The [documentation](https://netbeans.org/features/platform/all-docs.html) is really complete and if you're already familiar with desktop development you'll find it pretty easy to learn.

For what concern the interface with a server component I would create a set of RESTful API using Spring, or even a set of simple servlets. I recommend you to use an ORM like JPA or Hibernate; you'll get caching, pooling and schema flexibility for free. On the fat client side I usually build a REST client using Apache HTTPComponents. The use of HTTP make it easy to overcome firewalls, and security mechanism that are usually built to allow at least internet traffic.

The last hint I can provide is to use JSON for the payload you intend to exchange over the HTTP connection between the client and the server. JSON is compact, text based, and it can be converted easily from and to POJOs (Plain Old Java Objects) using [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

Comment: Thanks for your hints! But I do not want NetBeans and I was less talking about how to communicate with the server side (there we use a pure Java API anyways which is out of discussion).

My question was more about the actual Swing application starting and shutting down.

Comment: You mean how to start and stop the desktop application on the desktop (client) side?

Comment: No, I am talking of application wide error handling, setting up resources, safely exiting the application. Means: Not just System.extit(0) on some button event ;-)